# REGEXP_REPLACE How to loop through variable occurrences of a text string

Tags: regex, plsql, oracle11g, regexp-replace

I'm using an Oracle 11.g procedure. I found this example of `REGEXP_REPLACE` with only two arguments (input and pattern).  It works, but not optimally.  I'm trying to use `REGEXP_REPLACE` in order to loop through a variable number of occurrences of a particular text string that occurs after the text **base64,** and before the text **" />**
I can make it work for a single occurrence, but I can't make it loop properly.

```
Declare p_html    clob;
        l_image_clob  clob;
        l_image_count number;
Begin
p_html := '<p>Some header text base64,one start here and then this is the end one" /></p><p>Some header text base64,two start here and then this is the end two" /></p>';
l_image_count := REGEXP_COUNT(p_html, 'base64', 1, 'i');
If l_image_count > 0 Then
  For i In 1..l_image_count Loop
    l_image_clob := REGEXP_REPLACE(p_html, '(.*base64,)|(" />.*)');
    dbms_output.put_line(l_image_clob);
    -- code to process each occurrence individually.
  End Loop;
End If;
End;
```

What I'd like to see for data results are:

```
one start here and this is the end one 
two start here and this is the end two
```

The above example returns:

```
two start here and this is the end two
two start here and this is the end two
```

I've tried several options the `REXEXP_REPLACE` but I can't seem to make it work with the variable `i`.

Comment: Doesn't `REGEXP_REPLACE()` need 3 arguments? A string to search, a regexp, and a replacement for the regexp.

Comment: @Barmar no, with 2 arguments you remove the matched string [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions137.htm#SQLRF06302)

Answer (score 0):

This should help if you haven't already figured it out by now.  Basically the regex matches a string consisting of any characters up to (non-greedy) and including the string "base64 comma", followed by a remembered group of the next string of characters that are not a double-quote, followed by a double-quote and returns the remembered group part of that match, once for each occurrence of the string "base64" in the original string:

```
with tbl(p_html) as
( select '<p>Some header text base64,one start here and then this is the end one" /></p><p>Some header text base64,two start here and then this is the end two" /></p>'
  from dual
)
select REGEXP_substr(p_html, '.*?base64,([^"]*)"', 1, level, NULL, 1) text
from tbl
connect by level <= REGEXP_COUNT(p_html, 'base64', 1, 'i');


TEXT                                                                            
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
one start here and then this is the end one                                     
two start here and then this is the end two                                     

2 rows selected.
```

Wrap it in a cursor for loop, or load it into a collection for processing however you need to.